# How to navigate to next activity by using AlertDialog?

Tags: android

I am getting problem where to add intent and finish(); in alertdialog.

Here when user has internet connection then a alert will popup and says **You have internet connection** in alertdialog box and when user **click OK or Continue** button then he must continue to next activity.
If user have no internet connection then a alert will popup and says **You don't have internet connection** in alertdialog box and when user **click Exit** button application will close.

Code in **AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.java**

```
package com.example.detectinternetconnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity extends Activity {

// flag for Internet connection status
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

// Connection detector class
ConnectionDetector cd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btnStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_check);

    // creating connection detector class instance
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    /**
     * Check Internet status button click event
     * */
    btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // get Internet status
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

            // check for Internet status
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                // Internet Connection is Present
                // make HTTP requests
                showAlertDialog(AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this, "Internet Connection",
                        "You have internet connection", true);
//Here user has to continue next activity
            } else {
                // Internet connection is not present
                // Ask user to connect to Internet
                showAlertDialog(AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                        "You don't have internet connection.", false);
//here application should close
            }
        }

    });

}

/**
 * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
 * @param context - application context
 * @param title - alert dialog title
 * @param message - alert message
 * @param status - success/failure (used to set icon)
 * */
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    // Setting alert dialog icon
    alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);


    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

Code in **ConnectionDetector,java**

```
package com.example.detectinternetconnection;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
    this._context = context;
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null) 
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null) 
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
}
```

So tell me where to put intent to proceed next activity and finish(); to close the application.

Thank you...

Comment: I don't understand. Why are you stuck ? apparently you have everything so far, you just need to add the startActivity thing.

Comment: That I am thinking where put the startActivity and finish();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on clicking the alert dialog ok check the Internet is present or not.

```
 alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(isInternetPresent){
           Intent i=new Intent(Activity.this,targetActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
            }else{
             //code for exit here it send to home screen
      Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                      startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                      startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                      startActivity(startMain);
    }
            }
            });
```

Comment: after else{ i want close app when user don't internet

Comment: I added like this is this correct!!    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    if(isInternetPresent){

        Intent i=new Intent(AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);

    startActivity(i);
        }else{

        //code for exit
         AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this.finish();
        
            });
  // Showing Alert Message
  alertDialog.show();
 }
  }

Comment: not I am getting error at alertDialog.show();  as  **"Cannot refer to a non-final variable alertDialog inside an inner class defined in a different method"**

Comment: just finish() not as AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this.finish();

Comment: Yes now error are got cleared but in emulator When i Clicked on check internet status button a alertdialog popup and says No internet connect..

Comment: I tried to install in android mobile Says **Application not installed**.. why i am getting this error..

Comment: you are trying it in your mobile

Comment: Yes sir.. but in emulator working fine.. But when tried to install in mobile not going to install and says **Application not installed**

Comment: did you installed the application in your mobile

Answer (score 1):

Use `showAlertDialog` last parameter `status` to perform action on Ok button click according to the Internet connection status as :

```
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

           if(status){
             // cancel Alert Dialog
             // Move to Activity
           }else{
             // cancel Alert Dialog
             // close Activity
           }

    }
});
```

Comment: can u please add intent at if(status){   and after else{  so that i can add that and check

Comment: @user3260468 : you have done good code.i have told you location and  please first try yourself if face any issue then i will sure try to help you

Comment: But in emulator When i Clicked on **Check internet status** button a alertdialog popup and says No internet connect..   I tried to install in android mobile Says Application not installed.. why i am getting this error..

Comment: @user3260468 : in mobile you will need to chick install from unknown resources operation in settings to install unsigned apk